# Single Sign-On with Google Apps + App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, openid, google-apps, single-sign-on

Is it possible to achieve SSO with the built-in OpenId on App Engine? I've been trying to integrate a Marketplace app and get the user logged in when coming from Google Apps (the admin panel or universal navigation). I failed miserably, then now I found this:

"The one exception to this is applications which do hybrid OpenID/OAuth — whitelisting does not currently work with this approach." (from [here](http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/sso.html))

I assume that I have to implement OpenId using a library instead of using the built-in one to achieve SSO with Google Apps in my app? Or if it is possible with built-in OpenId, is there an example anywhere that shows how to do this?

Comment: You don't say specifically whether you confirmed that the marketplace app you are integrating does hybrid OpenID/OAuth or which marketplace app it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Later Google posted an article about how to do it in Python:

http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_python_gae.html

The summary is:

- You must whitelist your "OpenID realm" (the app domain) in the Marketplace manifest XML.
- The entry point used for the Google's universal navigation must contain the current Google Apps domain.
- The entry point in your app redirects the user passing the Google Apps domain as `federated_identity`.

For example:

```
from google.appengine.api import users

# [...]

login_url = users.create_login_url(dest_url='http://my-app.appspot.com/',
                                   _auth_domain=None,
                                   federated_identity=google_apps_domain_name)
self.redirect(login_url)
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in Java:

```
Set<String> attributesRequest = new HashSet<String>();
String loginRealm = "http://myapp.appspot.com"; //Important that it is exactly the same as in application-manifest.xml, watch out for trailing slashes.
String destinationURL = req.getRequestURI() + "?" + req.getQueryString();
String federatedIdentity = null;
String authDomain = req.getParameter("hd"); //hd is the default parameter name. Contains the google apps domain name of the user logging on. example.com for example.
String loginUrl = userService.createLoginURL(destinationURL, federatedIdentity, authDomain, attributesRequest);
```

Make sure to include

```
<Edition id="free">
    <Name>Cloud App Studio</Name>
    <Extension ref="navLink" />
    <Extension ref="realm" />
</Edition>
```

in the application-manifest.xml. That is, if it's free. The important part is to include the ref to realm.

Comment: Thanks Paul, this works great! Note to others: put this in the servlet that maps to /_ah/login_required as mentioned here: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html

Answer (score 1):

Err, I haven't got the full scoop on this feature, but I do use both JanRain Engage (which Stackoverflow uses) with GAE apps. I think openid4java could do the job as well.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't specify which language you are using. if it is java there is google library for openid+oauth.

http://code.google.com/p/step2/

Answer (score 1):

Did you already know [this link](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/chrome/webstore/docs/identify_user.html#how)?

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();

if (userService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
  User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
  /* ...Do something with user.getFederatedIdentity(), which is the OpenID URL. */
}
```