# Google App Engine Create New Google Account

Tags: java, google-app-engine, single-sign-on

I am working on a requirement in which I have to create new registration module for creating a new account on google. I plan to used google app engine with Java environment.

Now I have no idea for meet this requirement.

Can you advise me to create this module.

And I have another one question, does Google APP (Free Edition) use SSO or not?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding Gae does use sine sign on

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at documentation on GAE [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview)

And a small article written for authentication by me [here](http://cloudspring.com/google-app-engine-gae-java-api-part-3-getting-started-with-apis/)

When user is redirected to Google login screen, and he does not have an ID, he can create one ( I would first suggest you to work on part where user is forwarded to login screen and is asked to login, you will understand what I mean)

As far SSO, there are discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591434/single-sign-on-with-google-apps-app-engine) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163753/single-sign-on-on-google-app-engine-apps) which do suggest it can work with proper configuration. Hope this helps